# How can I prevent the main content from overlapping the header element on my HTML page?

Tags: html, css, css-position, z-index, overlapping

I'm encountering an issue on my HTML page where *the main content is overlapping the header element*, causing visual overlap and content obstruction. Despite my attempts to address the problem using the ***position and z-index properties*** in both my CSS and HTML files, I haven't been able to resolve the issue.

I need assistance in finding a solution to prevent the main content from overlapping the header element. How can I ensure that the main content displays correctly without overlapping the header? I'm open to any suggestions, insights, or alternative approaches to tackle this problem.

I was expecting that by using the position property with appropriate values **(such as relative, absolute, or fixed) and assigning a higher z-index value to the header element compared to the main content,** the header would remain visually above the main content, effectively preventing any overlap.

Unfortunately, despite implementing these techniques, the main content still overlaps the header element. I am seeking guidance and alternative solutions to ensure that the header and main content display properly without any visual overlap.

```css
.top_header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px var(--shadow-color);
  z-index: var(--z-fixed);
}

/* Nav */
.nav {
  height: var(--nav-height);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: var(--font-bold);
  margin: 0 1.5rem;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .nav_menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: var(--nav-height);
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: var(--dark-color);
    padding: 2rem;
    right: -100%;
    transition: right .2s;
  }

  .show {
    right: 0;
  }
}

.nav_toggle {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: var(--dark-color);
}

.nav_link {
  color: white;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  position: relative;
}

.link_item {
  margin-bottom: var(--mg-4);
}

.nav_link:hover::after, .active::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  background-color: var(--light-color);
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.23rem;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 1.3rem;
  border-radius: 2rem;
}

.nav_logo {
  width: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<header class="top_header">
      <nav class="nav bg_grid">
        <div class="logo_container">
          <img class="nav_logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="nav_menu" id="nav-menu">
          <ul class="nav_list">
            <li class="link_item"><a href="#" class="nav_link active">Home</a></li>
            <li class="link_item"><a href="#" class="nav_link">About</a></li>
            <li class="link_item"><a href="#" class="nav_link">Products</a></li>
            <li class="link_item"><a href="#" class="nav_link">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="nav_toggle" id="nav-toggle">
          <i class="bx bx-menu"></i>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
```

Comment: I would check out [mcve] as I created a quick snippet with test content and put a background color on top_header and didn't have problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the CSS property position sticky. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position. Might not work with older browsers. If you need to work with older browsers you could also just apply a margin top to the main content.

Comment: Answers should be more specific. Please see [answer] and consider copying the snippet from the question down here so you can demonstrate your solution.